# Upon creating of new data lead to posting on Facebook User/Group's Wall

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a MVC3 web apps where by creating a data in database, the content of that particular data will be posted to facebook wall as well.

For example, in database i creating a column like this:

```
Email: abc@abc.com

Messege: Hello World!
```

and I want this data to be publish at facebook wall, like:

```
Hello World! from abc@abc.com
```

Any recommended guidelines or tutorial? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the c# Facebook sdk could help you ...

```
    Dictionary<string, string> postArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postArgs["message"] = "Hello, world!";
api.Post("/userid/feed", postArgs);
```

taken from the docs here...

https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

other links...

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/

Comment: Thanks! So I will need to create an apps to grab my token first?

Comment: you need to register your app in case you want to interact with facebook api that's true... but for that see the second link...